# processing very large text files in parallel using multiprocessing and threading

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I have found several other questions that touch on this topic but none that are quite like my situation.

I have several very large text files (3+ gigabytes in size).

I would like to process them (say 2 documents) in parallel using `multiprocessing`. As part of my processing (within a single process) I need to make an API call and because of this would like to have each process have it's own `threads` to run asynchronously.

I have came up with a simplified example ( I have commented the code to try to explain what I think it *should* be doing):

```py
import multiprocessing
from threading import Thread
import threading
from queue import Queue
import time


def process_huge_file(*, file_, batch_size=250, num_threads=4):
    # create  APICaller instance for each process that has it's own Queue
    api_call = APICaller()

    batch = []

    # create threads that will run asynchronously to make API calls
    # I expect these to immediately block since there is nothing in the Queue (which is was
    # the api_call.run depends on to make a call 
    threads = []
    for i in range(num_threads):
        thread = Thread(target=api_call.run)
        threads.append(thread)
        thread.start()

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
    ####
    # start processing the file line by line
    for line in file_:
        # if we are at our batch size, add the batch to the api_call to to let the threads do 
        # their api calling 
        if i % batch_size == 0:
            api_call.queue.put(batch)
        else:
        # add fake line to batch
            batch.append(fake_line)


class APICaller:
    def __init__(self):
    # thread safe queue to feed the threads which point at instances
    of these APICaller objects
        self.queue = Queue()

    def run(self):
        print("waiting for something to do")
        self.queue.get()
        print("processing item in queue")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("finished processing item in queue")




if __name__ == "__main__":
    # fake docs
    fake_line = "this is a fake line of some text"
    # two fake docs with line length == 1000
    fake_docs = [[fake_line] * 1000 for i in range(2)]
    ####
    num_processes = 2
    procs = []
    for idx, doc in enumerate(fake_docs):
        proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=process_huge_file, kwargs=dict(file_=doc))
        proc.start()
        procs.append(proc)

    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()
```

As the code is now, "waiting for something to do" prints 8 times (makes sense 4 threads per process) and then it stops or "deadlocks" which is not what I expect - I expect it to start sharing time with the threads as soon as I start putting items in the Queue but the code does not appear to make it this far. I ordinarily would step through to find a hang up but I still don't have a solid understanding of how to best debug using `Threads` (another topic for another day).

In the meantime, can someone help me figure out why my code is not doing what it should be doing?

Comment: In your `process_huge_file` function, join threads after the `for line in file_` loop, not before it.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a few adjustments and additions and the code appears to do what it is supposed to now. The main adjustments are: adding a `CloseableQueue` class (from Brett Slatkins Effective Python Item 55), and ensuring that I call close and join on the queue so that the threads properly exit. Full code with these changes below:

```py
import multiprocessing
from threading import Thread
import threading
from queue import Queue
import time

from concurrency_utils import CloseableQueue


def sync_process_huge_file(*, file_, batch_size=250):
    batch = []
    for idx, line in enumerate(file_):
        # do processing on the text
        if idx % batch_size == 0:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            batch = []
            # api_call.queue.put(batch)
        else:
            computation = 0
            for i in range(100000):
                computation += i
            batch.append(line)


def process_huge_file(*, file_, batch_size=250, num_threads=4):
    api_call = APICaller()

    batch = []

    # api call threads
    threads = []
    for i in range(num_threads):
        thread = Thread(target=api_call.run)
        threads.append(thread)
        thread.start()

    for idx, line in enumerate(file_):
        # do processing on the text
        if idx % batch_size == 0:
            api_call.queue.put(batch)
        else:
            computation = 0
            for i in range(100000):
                computation += i
            batch.append(line)

    for _ in threads:
        api_call.queue.close()
    api_call.queue.join()

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()


class APICaller:
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = CloseableQueue()

    def run(self):
        for item in self.queue:
            print("waiting for something to do")
            pass
            print("processing item in queue")
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print("finished processing item in queue")
        print("exiting run")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # fake docs
    fake_line = "this is a fake line of some text"
    # two fake docs with line length == 1000
    fake_docs = [[fake_line] * 10000 for i in range(2)]
    ####
    time_s = time.time()
    num_processes = 2
    procs = []
    for idx, doc in enumerate(fake_docs):
        proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=process_huge_file, kwargs=dict(file_=doc))
        proc.start()
        procs.append(proc)

    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()

    time_e = time.time()

    print(f"took {time_e-time_s} ")


class CloseableQueue(Queue):
    SENTINEL = object()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def close(self):
        self.put(self.SENTINEL)

    def __iter__(self):
        while True:
            item = self.get()
            try:
                if item is self.SENTINEL:
                    return  # exit thread
                yield item
            finally:
                self.task_done()
```

As expected this is a great speedup from running synchronously - 120 seconds vs 50 seconds.